# How to use namespace declared and defined in a header file?

Tags: namespaces

I have a header file and a source file

**Header.h**

```
namespace na{

int gu = 25;
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int b = 10;
```

**Basics.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
extern int b;
using namespace std;
using namespace na;
void play(){ static int a = 20;
    a = a + 10;
    cout << a << "\n";
    b = b + 50;
    cout << b<<"\n";
    //Scout << gupta;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     extern int f;
     play();
     play();
     play();
     play();`enter code here`
     getchar();
     return 0;
 }
```

It throws the following error:

> a namespace with this name does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Adding Header.h   solves the problem